# Is it possible to apply the class changes to an element of selection.classed() in d3.js, or to set a CSS property value relative to its currentValue

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am using d3.js to add and remove classes to a selection of elements on mouseOver() and mouseOut() events. I'd like to make the class "isHovered" and make the values of the attributes I'm changing to be relative to the element's current value. Something like this:

```
function handleMouseOver(d, i) {
        d3.selectAll('.classToSelect')
        .classed('isHovered', 'true');
};
function handleMouseOut(d, i) {
        d3.selectAll('.classToSelect')
        .classed('isHovered', 'false');
};
```

and make the isHovered class change the elements size/color:

```
.isHovered {
    height:height*1.5;
    width:width*1.5;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

This adds the class, but doesn't actually make any changes to the elements attributes, except its classList. I'm trying to assign and unassigned the "isHovered" class, rather than having to store the pre-hovered size/color, and manually update them, and then manually revert back to them afterwards, which I don't think is possible since these elements are sized dynamically by d3.js scaling data:

[image: d3.js dynamically sized element width]

So, can I make these newly added class changes actually take effect, and can the effect be relative to an element's properties' current values?

Alternatively:

Is it possible to access the element's width:svgAnimatedWidth and Height:svgAnimatedHeight properties & values directly, so that I can change them and revert them back manually? How?

Comment: For now I am using:
.attr('width', (d3.select(this).node().width.animVal.value)*1.5 ) 
to retrieve the current width, and set the new width based on that for selected elements. I do the inverse on mouseOut.

Comment: Have you looked at using CSS variables?

Comment: I haven't, but from my quick reading just now it looks like that's basically just a placeholder? If I could dynamically change the value of the variable, that would be perfect.

Comment: JS can change the variables.

Comment: And those changes will be reflected on all elements of the class? Right now I'm able to assign an element a new class in their classList, but the properties of that class are not being applied to the elements.

Comment: Could you achieve what you're after with 'transform: scale(1.5)'? Or is it more than just mere scaling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways of altering the height/width on hover.

This snippet uses CSS variables to set the initial height and width in a class and then uses them to calculate new values in the isHovered class.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
div.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  div.classList.add('isHovered');
});
div.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  div.classList.remove('isHovered');
});
```

```css
div {
  --h: 100;
  --w: 200;
  height: calc(var(--h) * 1px);
  width: calc(var(--w) * 1px);
  background-color: blue;
}

.isHovered {
  --hhovered: calc(var(--h) * 1.5);
  --whovered: calc(var(--w) * 1.5);
  height: calc(var(--hhovered) * 1px);
  width: calc(var(--whovered) * 1px);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

It is also possible to alter CSS variables using JS style.setProperty and to read them using style.getPropertyValue.

As a complete alternative if the aim is just to increase the height and width of an element on hover then the CSS transform scale could be used.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

div:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

This has  the advantage (or disadvantage, depending on what effect is actually required) of not affecting surrounding elements' positioning.